# jQuery img with class .css not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I've been looking for hours now why the following code won't work:

```
naam = "div#" + $(naam).next('div').attr('id');
current = "img." + $(naam).attr('id');
$(current).css("border", "solid 4px #9966FF");
```

The div has an id with the same name as the class from the img:

```
<div id="michiel">
```

This is the image I want to use the code on:

```
<img src="Images/michielsmall.jpg" class="michiel, link" alt="Michiel">
```

As you can see I'm trying to change the border of the img with class `"michiel"`.

When I `console.log(current);`, Output is: `img.michiel`, which is correct.

I really don't know why this won't work, please help.

Comment: Remove the comma from `class="michiel, link"`

Comment: @Pekka I would be willing to venture a guess that good portion of programming errors come down to those pesky commas.

Comment: Commas aren't valid in class attributes. if you want multiple classes, simply separate them with spaces.

Comment: Also In your variable `naam` you're also referencing back to `naam`... I'm not sure if you can you do that ? But I may be wrong.

Comment: @vletech This isn't a problem, when I referenced back to naam when setting naam value, it was working as intended

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because of the **comma** in the class name

```
class="michiel, link"
              ^^------- Remove this
```

Supposed to be

```
class="michiel link"
```

OR .. If you want the **comma to be present** , then change your selector to

```
var current = "img." + $(naam).attr('id') + "\\,";
```

But this is not recommended

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/bRQ4U/)**

Comment: Oh god, you're right. How could I forget this!
It's weird though that he does give me the right class name when I wanted to retrieve it in naam = "div#" + $(this).attr('class');
This gave me classname "michiel" as intended

Comment: I removed the commas, but now my $(naam).fadeIn(600); doesn't work anymore.
Naam is retrieved like this:  naam = "div#" + $(this).attr('class');
$(this) is the picture <img src="Images/michielsmall.jpg" class="michiel link" alt="Michiel">

Comment: That won't work as the image has two classes right .. So  `$(this).attr('class')` will get you both `michiel link` .. SO there is no div with the `id ="michiel link"`

Answer (score 0):

`naam` is not defined. I made a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jmutv/) and looked in the chrome console.

#### Update

I changed your javascript to `$('.michiel').css('border', 'solid 4px #9966FF');` If you need it to be more specific, I'm sure you can take it from here.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmutv/2/